# How can I read the non public member "_disposed" from EF CORE DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I would like to check if ef core context is disposed.

I tried:

```
context.GetType().GetMembers(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)

context.GetType().GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)

context.GetType().GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
```

Not listing the property.

Comment: It's private for a reason. This is an X/Y problem. What problem were you trying to resolve when you decide to go down this route?

Comment: Why? `DbContext` implements `IDisposible`, so call it (or wrap in a `using`) to force it to dispose.

Comment: You can call `Dispose()` multiple times so just call it an extra time to be safe.

Comment: I just want to check if by any reason the current context is disposed, if it does I create another.

inside DbContext code there is a method CheckDisposed that uses this property and raises an exception if it's true, I can use this, but I would like to know if there is a way to just read the property as this check method does.

Comment: It's not a property, but field. e.g. `var _disposedField = typeof(DbContext).GetField("_disposed", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);`

Comment: My mistake was that I was getting type from my class that inherits from dbcontext, so it was returning null, by adding .BaseType.GetField worked!

Answer (score -1):

I do not know why anyone might need it, but you can do it this way:

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public override void Dispose()
    {
        IsDisposed = true;
        base.Dispose();
    }

    public bool IsDisposed { get; private set; }
}
```